# How to parse the multiple arguments separated by comma in ansible?

Tags: parsing, unix, ansible, yaml

I am completely new to ansible, and I have multiple arguments to pass to the YAML as below:

> ansible-playbook parse.yaml -e hi,hello

The YAML should split the 'hi,hello' without the delimiters one after the other:

> hi 
>   hello

I have searched through many web pages but I couldn't find anything helpful, is it even possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple

```
 ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml -e 'parameter1=hi parameter2=hello'
```

For nice output you can add "| sed 's/\n/\n/g'"

```
 ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml -e 'parameter1=hi parameter2=hello'| sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

cat ./hosts:

```
localhost
```

cat playbook.yml:

```
---
- name: Playbook
  hosts: all
  become: root
  tasks:
    - name: output parameter1
      debug: msg="{{ parameter1 }}" 

    - name: output parameter2
      debug: msg="{{ parameter2 }}" 

    - name: output both
      debug:
        msg: | 

             {{ parameter1 }}
             {{ parameter2 }}
```